# Why output is showing errors

Tags: c++

This is a code fro diamond tree problem of multiple inheritance
and according to me this code is cool but it is showing some error on compilation
..help me to figure the error

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A  //A Diamond tree problem
{
  int x;
public:
  A(int i) { x = i; }
  void print() { cout << x; }
};

class B: virtual public A
{
public:
  B():A(10) {  }
};

class C:  virtual public A 
{
public:
  C():A(20) {  }
};

class D: public B, public C{
};

int main()
{
    D d;
    d.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: It gives an error because `A` needs to have a default constructor. **Or** you need to add a constructor to `D` which calls the `A` constructor.

Answer (score 8):

It would be useful to see the error:

```
In constructor ‘D::D()’:
error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A()’
```

When using virtual inheritance, the virtual base class must be initialised by the most derived class. In this case, that is `D`; so in order to be able to instantiate `D`, it must initialise `A`:

```
class D: public B, public C
{
public:
    D():A(42) {}
};
```

Alternatively, you could provide `A` with a default constructor. Declaring any constructor will prevent the compiler from implicitly generating one for you.

Comment: Can you explain a little more? Wouldn't compiler provide a default constructor? is it a specific behavior of virtual inheritance

Comment: @bapusethi: You only get an implicit default constructor if you don't declare any constructors of your own. Declaring `A(int)` will prevent that. That's true for all classes, regardless of virtual inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide default construct for D and call A in member initialize list:

```
class D: public B, public C{
public:
   D():A(30){}
};
```

Or you could provide a default A constructor

```
A():x(0) {}
```